# VBA how to insert text into a cell that already contains text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contain some numbers in rows, I would like to convert to columns with "," in the end of the number, for example:

```
5001 5002 5003
```

After convert

```
5001,
5002,
5003,
```

I have this code already

```
Dim range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Set range1 = Application.Selection
Set range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, range1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
range1.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
rowIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In range1.Columns
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
    rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Rows.Count
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image: Image example]

Comment: Can you show (with a picture) how your data looks now, and how it should look after you done? Right now I'm confused wheather you want all values of each row in one cell (concatenated with commas) or you just want all cells with a comma behind the value.

Comment: Agreed. Some sample data (even a picture) and desired results would go a LONG way in helping us understand.

Comment: I think you'll want to do a `split` on the cell using a space delimiter and then join the array using `join` and a comma (`,`). But maybe I'm misunderstanding the aim, as are others.

Comment: Or you might be better of just using `replace` and replace your spaces with commas.

Comment: Picture attached,

Comment: So you want the data transposed, with a comma added after every value?  Looks like each of those are individual cell values in both the before and after conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something very basic (needs work to catch errors):

```
Sub TransposeWithComma()

Dim range1 As Range: Set range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Dim range2 As Range: Set range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
range2.Resize(range1.Columns.Count).Value = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(" & range1.Address & ")&"",""")

End Sub
```

- Let the user select a bunch of cells in a row, say `A1:G1`
- Let the user pick a single cell where you want the values transposed to
- Resize the single cell to match the source and concatenate the values from the source with a comma using `Evaluate`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Will add a quick mock-up of some code to capture an array then iterate through the array and print to cell.

```
dim arr as variant, i as long
arr = range(cells(4,1),cells(4,7)).value
for i = 1 to 7
    cells(3+i,10).value = arr(1,i) & ","
next i
```

Note this is untested, but should give an idea about what is being displayed in your updated post (aligns with the comment i made).